# Летит вёрстка на ios в приложении ionic

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic

Недавно я сделал приложение на ionic. В android приложение отображается и работает нормально. В браузерах chrome и safari - всё отлично. Но в ios симуляторах в xcode и на реальном устройстве что то происходит с вёрсткой. Фиксированные элементы - не фиксируются, иногда не работает скролл (страница либо стоит на одном месте, либо контент обрубается на середине и я листаю пустой экран). Самое интересное, что вёрстка не летит на модальных окнах (на страницах, созданных в контроллере anguraljs с помощью $ionicModal). Где искать корень проблемы? В css или настройках в xcode?

Comment: можете создать минимальный пример, где это воспроизводится и приложить к вопросу?

Comment: даже не знаю. выложить куда-нибудь приложение на ionic просто как сайт не получится и даже если выложу, то всё будет работать хорошо. проблема только на устройствах и эмуляторах ios. Могу скинуть куда-нибудь проект с приложением, который нужно будет открыть в xcode и запустить